# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate how to create executable file

Tags: visual-studio

I have visual studio 2010 ultimate. There is no  option to make executable file.
So how can I make executable files using this version of visual studio.

Comment: please help to fix this Guys

Comment: which language?? normally after building a c# project you will get something to execute

Answer (score 0):

Actually you've already created an .exe file by "building" your code that you tested in debugger mode. However your .exe file may require other files in order to deploy it onto another P/C. I recommend you read this information at the following link;

[click here to go on link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx)

Other than that you can actually find a copy of your current executeable in your application folders debug folder. May take a little searching. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 RC and I don't know if the file structure is the same for Visual Studio 2010 but for the application "counter" I look in "C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Counter\Counter\obj\Debug\Counter.exe.

Comment: Actually it is in the bin folder not in the obj one

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: my bad @Steve it's the bin foder